# svn log - filter out commits by comment data or by user

Tags: svn

I am using svn log to show the history of commits to some folder in the repository.

Is there a way to filter out commits done by specific user or that include some phrase in their comments?

Comment: Not natively, your best bet is to find a library in the language of your choice that does that. If it turns out you need to write it yourself, you might benefit from the more structured output `svn log --xml` generates.

Comment: if on unix-like os, you can pipe the output to grep, awk, sed and friends

Comment: If you’re on Windows, TortoiseSVN does it pretty well.